# How can i remove the outside gridlines of QTableWidget and QHeaderView?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to create a custom QTableView for which i would like to not display the outside grid lines, which would mean omitting the bottom and right lines for each cell. Using stylesheets, it seems that i can only change the gridline colors and the borders of QHeaderView. I would also like to make the gridlines a bit thicker and be somehow able to only view the inner lines.

Current Stylesheet:

```
QTableWidget {
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
gridline-color: #9370DB;
}


QHeaderView::section:vertical { 
border-top: 1px solid #9370DB
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal { 
border: 0px;
border-left: 1px solid #9370DB
}
```

Current output looks like this:

[image]

I can also see that the header lines and the gridlines are misaligned, but that might be solved by having the same line thickness everywhere.

Full code for testing:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *  # type: ignore
from PySide6.QtGui import *  # type: ignore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *  # type: ignore
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.indicatorsLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.indicatorsLayout.setObjectName(u"indicatorsLayout")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.indicatorsLayout)

        self.listboxLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.listboxLayout.setObjectName(u"listboxLayout")
        self.listbox = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        if (self.listbox.columnCount() < 5):
            self.listbox.setColumnCount(5)
        if (self.listbox.rowCount() < 10):
            self.listbox.setRowCount(10)
        self.listbox.setObjectName(u"listbox")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.listbox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.listbox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.listbox.setStyleSheet(u"QTableWidget {\n"
                                   "padding-left: 50px;\n"
                                   "padding-right: 50px;\n"
                                   "gridline-color: #9370DB;\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "\n"
                                   "\n"
                                   "QHeaderView::section:vertical { \n"
                                   "border-top: 1px solid #9370DB\n"
                                   "}\n"
                                   "\n"
                                   "QHeaderView::section:horizontal { \n"
                                   "border: 0px;\n"
                                   "border-left: 1px solid #9370DB\n"
                                   "}")
        self.listbox.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listbox.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.listbox.setRowCount(10)
        self.listbox.setColumnCount(5)
        self.listbox.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.listbox.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)

        self.listboxLayout.addWidget(self.listbox, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.listboxLayout)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not display the outside grid lines"? Do you mean that you don't want to see the bottom and right lines of the last row and columns?

Comment: @musicamante yes, sorry. I will edit my post to make it more clear. It should look like the tic-tac-toe grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid line always has a width of 1 pixel, and it cannot be changed. The misalignment is due to the fact that the grid line is always drawn on the bottom and right of each index, while you're setting the border of the header on top or left of each section.

This also means that the grid lines are always shown around all items, including the last row and column.

The solution is to completely disable the grid, and set the borders for the items only in the same way as you're drawing the headers; in this way, you can also set the thickness of the "grid". The drawback of this approach is that styling the items will override the default style painting of the delegate, so you must also specify the selection color.

[image: result of the applied stylesheet]

```
QTableWidget {
    qproperty-showGrid: "false";
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

QTableWidget::item {
    border-top: 2px solid #9370DB;
    border-left: 2px solid #9370DB;
}

QTableWidget::item:selected {
    background: palette(highlight);
}


QHeaderView::section:vertical { 
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid #9370DB
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal { 
    border: 0px;
    border-left: 2px solid #9370DB
}
```

A slightly different approach uses both a stylesheet *and* an item delegate: all borders are drawn (using half of the wanted size), excluding the last section of the headers, and the grid is drawn using the delegate, and in this case the styling is *not* set for the `::item` selector, ensuring that it always respects the internal rendering provided by the style.

```
class GridDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('#9370DB'), 1)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        qp.save()
        qp.setPen(self.pen)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        lastRow = index.model().rowCount() - 1
        lastCol = index.model().columnCount() - 1
        if index.row() < lastRow and index.column() < lastCol:
            qp.drawRect(opt.rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
        else:
            qp.drawLine(opt.rect.bottomLeft(), opt.rect.topLeft())
            qp.drawLine(opt.rect.topLeft(), opt.rect.topRight())
            if index.row() < lastRow:
                qp.drawLine(opt.rect.bottomLeft(), opt.rect.bottomRight())
            elif index.column() < lastCol:
                qp.drawLine(opt.rect.topRight(), opt.rect.bottomRight())
        qp.restore()
        super().paint(qp, opt, index)


# ...
tableWidget.setItemDelegate(GridDelegate(tableWidget))
tableWidget.setStyleSheet('''
    QTableWidget {
        qproperty-showGrid: "false"; 
        padding-left: 50px; 
        padding-right: 50px; 
    }

    QTableCornerButton::section { 
        border: 0px; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #A370DB; 
        border-right: 1px solid #A370DB; 
    }

    QHeaderView::section:vertical { 
        border: 1px solid #9370DB; 
        border-left: none; 
    }

    QHeaderView::section:vertical:last { 
        border-bottom: none; 
    }

    QHeaderView::section:horizontal { 
        border: 1px solid #9370DB; 
        border-top: none; 
    }

    QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last { 
        border-right: none; 
    }
''')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed the fact that i could use the borders to draw the grid rather than the grid itself.

Comment: @conopizda2 you're welcome. I've updated the answer including a slightly different method to ensure style consistency.